# Matlab: problems with neural network training

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I´m trying to train a neural network using nprtool and also manually, calling newpr and train methods. **I use samples oriented as rows, instead of default as columns**:

[image: nprtool]

Using nprtool there is no problem, but when I call to the automatically generated M-file, the output is:

```
??? Error using ==> network.train at 145
Targets are incorrectly sized for network.
Matrix must have 24 columns.

Error in ==> create_pr_net at 29
[net,tr] = train(net,inputs,targets);
```

My inputs are 140x24, and my targets are 140x3.

The generated code by Matlab is:

```
function net = create_pr_net(inputs,targets)
%CREATE_PR_NET Creates and trains a pattern recognition neural network.
%
%  NET = CREATE_PR_NET(INPUTS,TARGETS) takes these arguments:
%    INPUTS - RxQ matrix of Q R-element input samples
%    TARGETS - SxQ matrix of Q S-element associated target samples, where
%      each column contains a single 1, with all other elements set to 0.
%  and returns these results:
%    NET - The trained neural network
%
%  For example, to solve the Iris dataset problem with this function:
%
%    load iris_dataset
%    net = create_pr_net(irisInputs,irisTargets);
%    irisOutputs = sim(net,irisInputs);
%
%  To reproduce the results you obtained in NPRTOOL:
%
%    net = create_pr_net(inputs,targets);

% Create Network
numHiddenNeurons = 2000;  % Adjust as desired
net = newpr(inputs,targets,numHiddenNeurons);
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 90/100;  % Adjust as desired
net.divideParam.valRatio = 5/100;  % Adjust as desired
net.divideParam.testRatio = 5/100;  % Adjust as desired

% Train and Apply Network
[net,tr] = train(net,inputs,targets);
outputs = sim(net,inputs);

% Plot
plotperf(tr)
plotconfusion(targets,outputs)
```

I am using Matlab R2010a.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in Matlab help file:

INPUTS - RxQ matrix of Q R-element input samples
TARGETS - SxQ matrix of Q S-element associated target samples

You probably need a **transpose** of input and target matrix, before calling the Matlab train function manually.

`Input = Input';` and 
`Taget = Target';`

Comment: I did it, but the results were not the same. I don´t know why.

Comment: Results were not same, meaning it could compile? Results may depend on the pre-processing of input and target; nprtool may do a secrete normalization. Just guess.